# Gestures no angular 9 com hammerjs

Tags: angular, hammerjs

Estou tentando utilizar o `hammerjs` para capturar o `swipe` na versão mobile da minha aplicação, porém, o evento `swipe` parece não ser reconhecido já que o `console.log` dentro dele não é logado.

App.module.ts

```
...
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';
import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class HammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = { swipe: { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL } as any };
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: HammerConfig },
...
```

meucomponente.component.ts

```
swipe(evt) {
  console.log(evt);
  const x = Math.abs(evt.deltaX) > 40 ? (evt.deltaX > 0 ? 'right' : 'left') : '';

  this.eventText += `${x}<br/>`;
}
```

meucomponente.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (swipe)="swipe($event)">
  <div formArrayName="iatas"
    *ngFor="let iata of myForm.controls.iatas?.value; let i = index; trackBy:trackByFn">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Informe a Gaiola</mat-label>
        <input matInput name="gaiola" type="text" formControlName="gaiola">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select formControlName="iata" [multiple]="true" placeholder="Iatas">
          <app-mat-select-search [formControl]="iataMultiFilter"></app-mat-select-search>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let iata of filteredIata | async" [value]="iata.id">
            {{iata.descricao}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="removeGroup(i)">
        <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Se eu usar o evento `(click)`, o log é feito normalmente. Onde posso estar errando ?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zcxxyg) simplificado de exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de perder o dia todo, encontrei o problema, deixo aqui para futura referência.

É necessário importar o `HammerModule` do pacote `@angular/platform-browser` no `app.module.ts` e lista-lo nos `imports` do mesmo arquivo.

```
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, HammerGestureConfig, HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    ...
    HammerModule
  ],
```